# pytest console output

Tags: python, subprocess, pytest

В тесте запускается subprocess с таймаутом. Если таймаут превышен, то помимо тела теста в консоли появляется еще и другие функции связанные с subprocess. Как их убрать и оставить только (тело теста, stdout и stderr - последний желательно тоже как-то уменьшить)?

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос, что значит "появляется еще и другие функции связанные с subprocess"

Comment: в traceback при ошибке (timeout) также попадает run метод сабпроцесса. А у него очень объёмный Doc. В итоге, чтобы просто посмотреть где возникла ошибка, приходится листать всё дерево ошибок. Пока нашел выход такой "pytest --tb=short"

Comment: Самый простой способ ужать стектрейс - запускать `subprocess.communicate` в try-блоке и отлавливать `TimeoutExpired`. В except-блоке можно либо кинуть ту же ошибку снова, либо использовать `pytest.fail` с информативным сообщением.